# I cant add more then one user in database

Tags: python, flask

I want to add users in group table, i'm checking user in all group member if and then if he is already in table i flash the message and if not i add user to the group. but it only does for the first user. and the rest  the logic evaluate false

```
   @main.route('/join-classroom/<int:classroom_id>/<int:user_id>/')
@login_required
def join_classroom(classroom_id, user_id):
    classroom = Classroom.query.filter_by(id=classroom_id).first()

if classroom is None:
    flash('Invalid classname')
    return redirect(url_for('main.classrooms'))
else:
# check if user aleady added or on request
    classroomMembers = ClassroomMember.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).all()
    for classroomMember in classroomMembers:
        if (classroomMember.user_id == user_id) and (classroomMember.classroom_id == classroom_id):
            flash('You are already in Group ')
            return redirect(url_for('main.classrooms'))

        elif (classroomMember.user_id != user_id) and (classroomMember.classroom_id != classroom_id):
            classroomMember = ClassroomMember(classroom_id=classroom_id, user_id=user_id)
            db.session.add(classroomMember)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Your request has been sent successfully')
            return redirect(url_for('main.classrooms'))

        elif classroomMember.user_id is None:
            classroomMember = ClassroomMember(classroom_id=classroom_id, user_id=user_id)
            db.session.add(classroomMember)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Your request has been sent successfully')
            return redirect(url_for('main.classrooms'))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you request

```
classroomMembers = ClassroomMember.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).all()
```

you get in `classroomMembers` records with `user_id=user_id` and only such records.
That's way only the first `if` clause can be `True` and code in two other `elif` will never be executed.

So you need to check if a person in a group and add there if not. And if a person does not exist create a new one. For instance like so:

```
classroomMembers = ClassroomMember.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).all()
if classroomMembers:
    classroomMember = classroomMembers[0]
    if classroomMember.classroom_id == classroom_id:
        flash('You are already in Group ')
        return redirect(url_for('main.classrooms'))
    else:
        classroomMember.classroom_id = classroom_id
        db.session.add(classroomMember)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('You were added to the Group')
        return redirect(url_for('main.classrooms'))
else:
    classroomMember = ClassroomMember(classroom_id=classroom_id, user_id=user_id)
    db.session.add(classroomMember)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Your request has been sent successfully')
    return redirect(url_for('main.classrooms'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with

```
@main.route('/join-classroom/<int:classroom_id>/<int:user_id>/')
```

@login_required
def join_classroom(classroom_id, user_id):
    classroom = Classroom.query.filter_by(id=classroom_id).first()

```
if classroom is None:
    flash('Invalid classname')
    return redirect(url_for('main.classrooms'))

else:
    classroomMember = ClassroomMember.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).filter_by(classroom_id=classroom_id).first()

    if classroomMember is None:
        classroomMemberUser = ClassroomMember(classroom_id=classroom_id, user_id=user_id)
        db.session.add(classroomMemberUser)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your request has been sent successfully')
        return redirect(url_for('main.classrooms'))

    else:
        flash("You are already in the Group")
        return redirect(url_for('main.classrooms'))
```